Existence of an $\alpha$-Hölder continuous function whose graph has positive Hausdorff measure of maximal dimension
It is standard that if $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, then its graph has Hausdorff dimension at most $2-\alpha$. My naive expectation was that "most" graphs of $\alpha$-Hölder continuous functions would not only attain that dimension but also have positive $\mathcal{H}^{2-\alpha}$ measure. However, whenever I have seen specific functions constructed to have their graph attain the maximal dimension $2-\alpha$, it is usually proved by showing that the graph must have Hausdorff dimension at least $2-\alpha-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, and I cannot find a single example in the literature of an $\alpha$-Hölder continuous function (with $0<\alpha<1$) whose graph is proven to definitively have positive $\mathcal{H}^{2-\alpha}$ measure. Does any such function actually exist in the first place?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911127/hausdorff-measure-of-a-smooth-curve

The Weierstrass function? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03986

@MartinHairer I saw that paper when searching the literature previously, and, unfortunately, I confess that even under further inspection I can't find the specific place where they prove (or imply) the Weierstrass function (or a Weierstrass-type function) has a graph of positive measure of maximal dimension. Could you point me to the page/line?

Iirc the Hausdorff dimension of the Weierstrass function in some cases is still not known. So this could be a genuine gap in the literature.

@NateRiver FWIW, I actually came upon this question trying to solve your problem about approximating $C^\alpha$ functions by singular functions, before I saw the answer posted here on MO by Martin Hairer. I showed that $\mathcal{H}^{2-\alpha}(\Gamma_f) \lesssim [f-g]_\alpha \mathcal{H}^1(\Gamma_g)$ (where $\Gamma_h$ is the graph of $h$), so here I am thinking I'm done because this means that no $C^\alpha$ function whose graph has positive $\mathcal{H}^{2-\alpha}$ measure can be approximated by singular functions, but perhaps we don't even know such a function exists!

@elihs Thanks for trying out the problem! Questions about Hausdorff measure are always really sharp and fascinating.

What should work is a so-called "Bedford-McMullen carpet with uniform fibers", which can be used to make continuous functions of arbitrary Hausdorff dimension in $(1,2)$, and positive and finite Hausdorff measure for that dimension. See for example Section 4.6 of Binder-Hakobyan-Li (https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.02350) for details of the construction and additional references. Holder continuity of the correct exponent is not specifically addressed in the linked paper, but it is fairly evident from the construction.

Thank you! I've worked out enough of the details to be fairly confident this specific construction works, but in case there is any doubt, as I was working on it, I followed one of the citations in the paper you linked to a book "Fractals in Probability and Analysis" by Bishop and Peres, and this specific question was exercise 5.52!

Yes. Let $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is $1$-Hölder and its $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is $1>0$.

I should have specified that I am only interested in the case when $0<\alpha<1$, I've edited the question accordingly.
